# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2014, sqldataadapter

EDIT: I answered my question below, but can't accept it yet.

I'm using C# and SQL2014. I know this question is everywhere and the typical answer is to use the universal format, but that's not what I'm looking for. I have two scenarios. One works and one does not and that is what I am concerned with. Both are using the same stored procedure (albeit in different databases). If I edit the stored procedure to be a command and manually set the parameters to the same thing I am setting them to in C#, both work. Both scenarios are exactly the same except different databases, so here is what I am doing.

```
cmd = new sqlcommand......
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;            
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", "3/16/2015");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", "12:00 AM");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endTime", "1:00 AM");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt); //Error
```

What is interesting is that it only fails when @date is set to "3/16/2015" I've tried about 6 other dates all around that and it all works fine. That being said, this date works fine on the other database. Does anyone have an idea of what this could be? In the stored procedure, these parameters get set to SMALLDATETIME. If need be, I can try to put some of the stored procedure in here.

Here is the part of the stored procedure that causes the issue to happen:

```
@date SMALLDATETIME,
@startTime SMALLDATETIME,
@endTime SMALLDATETIME


 --[DATE] is a smalldatetime column in the database
 WHERE
 [DATE] = @date --ERROR HAPPENS BECAUSE OF THIS
```

EDIT: Sorry for all of the confusion. After more debugging, it looks like the actual problem may be coming from this statement in the procedure:

```
 SELECT 
 DATEDIFF(mi, '00:00:00', [START]) AS [START], 
 CASE WHEN [END] = '00:00:00' THEN 1440 
 ELSE DATEDIFF(mi, '00:00:00', [END]) END AS [END]  
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: Can't you pass a date object?

Comment: Yes, I've tried passing in 3 datetimes as well and get the same issue.

Comment: Does the procedure also fail, with the same parameter values, if you execute it from the SQL Manager directly?

Comment: No, it works fine for both databases. That's why I'm kind of stuck debugging wise. Not sure what to try next.

Comment: My next step would be to start adding "print" commands into the stored procedure to produce a message output (to try to get more details of step of the failure). I have never had to do this but apparently "This is done by creating a SqlInfoMessageEventHandler delegate and listen for the InfoMessage event on the SqlConnection class"

Comment: Ok, I did something similar and have determined that the error occurs on the comparison of [DATE] = @date in the WHERE clause that I show in my question. I'll mark it above. The [DATE] column of my table is a smalldatetime

Comment: I updated my question. It looks like the issue was something else.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably based on the internal date format set up for the databases.  I would recommend that you use ISO standard formats in all your code so pass in:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", "2015-03-16");
```

Answer (score 0):

The String "3/16/2015" is something that will break unless you have hard coded the regional settings in the thread to US English in some fashion.

Have you tried being more specific with the SQL Parameter?
Sorry for the VB Syntax but I'd be guessing the C# equivalent...

```
Dim dt As Date = DateTime.ParseExact("3/16/2015", "M/d/yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("us-en"))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@date", dt) With {.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallDateTime})
```

Comment: I just saw your SP code, why are you converting your date time to a varchar to pass it to a command that accepts date time values (datediff) ? this all seems very unusual and error prone way to do something.

Comment: That's just how it was when I came across the issue. I just tried passing in 3 DateTimes and explicitly setting the SQLDBType to SmallDateTime and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was using this statement in the procedure:

DATEDIFF(mi, '00:00:00', [END])

[END] column was an nvarchar that had 24:00:00 set as midnight instead of 00:00:00.

Thanks to everyone that helped me debug this.